# Continuous Previous and Next Post Links in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

What I have is a page which displayed a post from a category and at the bottom there's a previous and next post link. The problem I have is that when it gets to the last one, I want to loop back to the start. It works going to the end if you're on the first one, just not back to beginning if you're on the last, it's just displaying the last post if you're on the last post.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php 
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true );
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false );
$prev_post_id = $prev_post->ID;
$next_post_id = $next_post->ID;
?>

<?php if ($prev_post_id == '') {
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'cat=4' ));

  while($query->have_posts()):
       $query->the_post();
       $prev_post_id = $query->post->ID;
  endwhile;
} ?>
<?php if ($next_post_id == '') {
  $query2 = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'cat=4'    ));
  while($query2->have_posts()):
       $query2->the_post();
       $next_post_id = $query2->post->ID;
  endwhile;
} ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev_post_id); ?>" class="prev-footer-item">
  <div class="prev-inner">
    <h3 class="gamma"><?php echo get_the_title($prev_post_id ); ?></h3>
    <h4 class="delta"><?php the_field('subtitle', $prev_post_id ); ?></h4>
    <div class="footer-overlay"></div>
  </div>
 </a>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_post_id); ?>" class="next-footer-item">
  <div class="next-inner">
    <h3 class="gamma"><?php echo get_the_title($next_post_id); ?></h3>
    <h4 class="delta"><?php the_field('subtitle', $next_post_id); ?></h4>
    <div class="footer-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

I'm sure it's something quite obvious I'm missing, right?

Update:
Working Prev Posts:

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  as1_posts.ID FROM as1_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND as1_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (as1_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR as1_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY as1_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Not Working Next Posts:

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  as1_posts.ID FROM as1_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND as1_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (as1_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR as1_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY as1_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: +1 for posting your code - so many people don't!

Comment: In that code, `'orderby' => 'ASC'` seems to make no sense? E.g., `'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything that is jumping out at me, but I've added an `if` statement to both of your loops (to prevent errors), added `wp_reset_postdata()` after each loop, and removed the need for `$query` and `$query2` - you can just use `$query` for both if you don't wish to use the query results for anything other than this.

Another thought - are you certain `get_adjacent_post()` returns `''` for the Post ID if it doesn't exist? Could it be `null`, or `'0'` for example. May be worth doing `var_dump($next_post_id)` and checking.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention, `get_adjacent_post()` assumes that the `post_type` of the adjacent post is the same the one you are currently viewing. I can't see this being an issue though, as you've already said it works the other way around, but it's something to bear in mind for the future.

```
<?php
if($prev_post_id === '') :

    $query = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'cat=4'));

    if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) :
        $query->the_post();
        $prev_post_id = get_the_ID();
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;

if($next_post_id === '') :

    $query = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'cat=4'));

    if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) :
            $query->the_post();
            $next_post_id = get_the_ID();
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
?>
```

Comment: Cheers.I've check what `get_adjacent_post()` was returning and you're right, it was `null`. I've changed the if statement to check for that and it's still only returning the current post you're on. It's still not working with your code though :(

And yep, it's the same post type.

Comment: Ok, after `$query = ...`, put `echo '<pre>'; print_r($query); echo '</pre>';`. This will output the results of the whole query, and you can see exacly what WP is up to. Look for `[request]`, this is the actual query that is sent to MySQL. It's a good place to look for clues as to why you are getting no results.

Comment: Ok, I've got the request data. I'm not really sure what I should deduce from it but I did notice the one for previous posts(working) is a lot shorter of a query than those for next posts(not working).

update in original post.

Comment: Second thought, it was because I tried changing `'cat=4'` to `'cat' => 4`. They're equal, the same string in fact.

Comment: Odd! You'll notice the statement `INNER JOIN` in the one that is not working - this is correct, the one that is working is just grabbing the first post, regardless of `cat`. Ok, can you try (after `$query = ...` again) this - `$wpdb->last_result;` and `$wpdb->last_error;`. This will tell you the lastet query result and error, so you can see if the query is actaully working.

Comment: GOT IT! It was because I was using `orderby` instead of `order`... Been trying to suss this one out for weeks.. Asked 3 different places and no one noticed it hehe. Wouldn't of noticed it though if you hadn't mentioned that `print_r($query)` though :) Mucho thanks dude! I'd +1 if I could!

Comment: Ha ha, I looked at that and didn't even notice! Glad you got it sorted.